# React not render the well known folder under public directory

Tags: java, android, create-react-app, server-side-rendering, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am on react.js including SSR using Razzle, having the issue to fetch the url

> somesitename.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

What I have did was to create the .well-known folder under public folder. Now paste my assetlinks.json file inside .well-known folder.

I have checked that it is properly rendered in my development but in server it is not accessed.
My code is stored in ubuntu 20 LTS.

I have tried to add link in my server.js file as all html is render here as my site is in SSR.

```
<link rel="assetlinks.json file" href="https://www.somesitename.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json" />
```

But no luck. Can anyone suggest me how to do this?
Any help, suggestion or interactions is really appreciable

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in the nginx server. Nginx not allow to server the .well-known folder.

So here are some steps by which we can achieve this types of issues:

> Step 1:

Create the assetlinks.json file under some directory. I have used under this:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/assetlinks.json
```

> Step 2:

Create the location block on the nginx.conf files

```
location = /.well-known/assetlinks.json {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   try_files /assetlinks.json =404;
}
```

> Step 3:

Run command to restart nginx:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Voila! your file will be render under the url i.e domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json